# Trying to find biggest and smallest number in 20 user entered numbers using For Loop

Tags: java

Im trying to get this program to take 20 user inputted numbers and find the smallest and biggest out of the 20. Why is this code here not working? It must be done in a For Loop as that's what the assignment requires.

This is an example output: 
Hit Enter to Begin

Enter a number
4
Enter a number
4
Enter a number
4
Enter a number
4
Enter a number
5
Enter a number
2
Enter a number
3
Enter a number
4
Enter a number
5
Enter a number
7
Enter a number
2
Enter a number
3
Enter a number
4
Enter a number
5
Enter a number
6
Enter a number
2
Enter a number
3
Enter a number
4
Enter a number
5
Enter a number
3
4 is the bigger number.
3 is the smallest number.

Why isn't 7 coming as biggest and 2 as smallest?

```
import java.io.*;

import java.util.Scanner; 

import java.text.*;

public class Unit3_Lesson4_16

{

static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 

public static void main() {

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);   

DecimalFormat mf = new DecimalFormat("'$'###,###,###.00");    
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.###"); 


int i, nb, smaller=0, bigger=0, current;

String start;

System.out.println("Hit Enter to Begin");
start = scanner.nextLine();

System.out.println("Enter a number");
nb = in.nextInt(); 



for (i=1; i<=19; i++)
{
    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    current = in.nextInt();

    if (current < nb)
    {
        bigger = nb;
        smaller = current;
    }
    else 
    {
        smaller = nb;
        bigger = current;
    }
    }


System.out.println(bigger + " is the bigger number.");
System.out.println(smaller + " is the smallest number.");


}

}
```

Comment: Ok, what have you done so far? What research have you done to solve this question? Also, we need to know what the problem is before we can help you. "Why is this code here not working?" is not a very helpful question. Something like, why is my code outputting 13 instead of 4? is a better question

Comment: I asked other people that I know but they didn't help and I was hoping somewhere here would be able to provide clarity on this program in general.

Comment: Can you tell us what about your code is not working? What is the current behaviour? What SHOULD it be doing instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's nb for? This should work:

```
for (i=0; i<20; i++)
{
    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    current = in.nextInt();

    if (current < smaller)
    {
        smaller = current;
    }

    if(current > bigger)
    {
        bigger = current;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are making this more complicated than it needs to be. You should only need bigger, smaller and current variables (get rid of nb).

The reason why bigger and smaller are incorrect is because of your making incorrect assignments after your comparisons. If the new value you just read in (current) is greater than bigger or less than smaller you only need make one assignment.

For some reason you are making assignments on both bigger AND smaller. This is one part of your code that is wrong (there are more than a few improvements you can make to make concise).

MbDavis has given you a perfect working solution. Go accept his answer and for future reference try not to post homework assignments. It's kinda taboo.

Comment: no problem. You can accept an answer if solved your problem. MBDavis gave you all you need to fix your code. I just told you why yours wasn't working :)

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int sm, bg, curr;
    //in.nextLine will consume the nextline when you hit enter.
    System.out.println("Hit Enter to Begin");in.nextLine();


    //We initialize smallest number and biggest number with the first given number
    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    sm = bg = in.nextInt();


    for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        curr = in.nextInt();

        //Checks input vs sm and bg
        sm = (curr < sm ? curr : sm);
        bg = (curr > bg ? curr : bg);
    }

    //Output
    System.out.println(sm + " is the bigger number.\n" + bg + " is the smallest number.");
}
}
```